# Running jar doesn't work

Tags: java, linux, jar, raspberry-pi, manifest

We are trying to make a jar out of our class files but somehow it does not work. The creation of the jar-file works fine with

```
jar -cvfm client.jar Mainfest.txt /home/pi/Desktop/Client/*.class
```

But when we try to run it comes with a classnodefferror. Our application is using 2 property files - one for database and one for log4j.

The directory and the one subdirectory included looks like this:
See [link](http://dinbab.dk/err_images/) - image nr. 1 and 2

[image: image nr 1]

[image: image nr 2]

When we try to execute the jar file it shows this error: 
(See link image 3)

[image: image 3]

Normally when we run it, we type (see link image 4)

[image: image 4]

And the manifest-file looks like this (see link image 5)

[image: image 4]

We have tried different solutions like changing paths, leaving out environment (-D) etc. and we really can't figure out what we do wrong.

Comment: did you check that the log4j jar file you have actually contains the class file? did you try to set your CLASSPATH environment variable to each jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. It is better to explicitly mention each included JAR file in the manifest - wildcards like * isnt working too well
2. You can't use absolute paths in a JAR file - use relative paths instead

So, 1) change Manifest.txt to

```
Main-Class: Client
Class-Path: . includes/log4j-1.2.17.jar includes/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar includes/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar includes/RXTXcomm-2.2pre2.jar  includes/..... (repeat for all pi4j JAR files)
```

And, 2) copy ALL the JAR files you need (including RXTXcomm-2.2pre2.jar and the pi4j JARs) into the include/ subdirectory, and change command to

```
jar -cvfm client.jar Manifest.txt *.class *.properties includes/*
```